# POW function and xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Working on a specific calculation, got some great help last time! Getting an error now:

```
Too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
```

But there are two arguments! The division of *twodouble* and *onedouble* will result in one number, the other *(1.0/3)*, being the second argument. Ideas? (Code is below).

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender{
    NSString *oneField = self.one.text;
    NSString *twoField = self.two.text;
    double resultInNum;
    double onedouble = [oneField doubleValue];
    double twodouble = [twoField doubleValue];
    resultInNum = pow((twodouble/onedouble),(1.0/3))*.999)*5.005;
    NSString *finalValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.3f", resultInNum];
    self.result.text = finalValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
resultInNum = pow((twodouble/onedouble),(1.0/3))*.999)*5.005;
```

Should be:

```
resultInNum = pow(twodouble/onedouble, 1.0/3)*0.999*5.005;
```

Just to let you know: pow is a C function and doesn't use a messaging system like Obj-C methods. My gut instinct is telling me you might be thinking like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many parentheses. Look carefully. You're only passing one argument to the pow function.

```
resultInNum = ((pow(twodouble/onedouble),(1.0/3));
```

should be

```
resultInNum = pow((twodouble/onedouble),(1.0/3));
```

**EDIT:** It looks like you updated your code after I posted my answer. You're still messing up the parentheses.

```
pow((twodouble/onedouble),(1.0/3))*.999)*5.005;
```

should be:

```
pow((twodouble/onedouble),(1.0/3))*.999*5.005;
```

Comment: If you keep having these kinds of problems, consider breaking out all the nested values. There's no reason to waste brain cycles trying to understand dense lines of code.